# Regex pattern works in Lua but not in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need to use regex in C# to split up something like "21A244" where

- The first two numbers can be 1-99
- The letter can only be 1 letter, A-Z
- The last three numbers can be 111-999

So I made this match
"([0-9]+)([A-Z])([0-9]+)"

but for some reason when used in C#, the match functions just return the input string. So I tried it in Lua, just to make sure the pattern was correct, and it works just fine there.

Here's the relevant code:

```
var m = Regex.Matches( mdl.roomCode, "(\\d+)([A-Z])(\\d+)" );

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print( "Count: " + m.Count );
```

And here's the working Lua code in case you were wondering

```
local str = "21A244"
print(string.match( str, "(%d+)([A-Z])(%d+)" ))
```

Thank you for any help

EDIT: Found the solution

```
var match = Regex.Match(mdl.roomCode, "(\\d+)([A-Z])(\\d+)");
var group = match.Groups;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print( "Count: " + group.Count );

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("houseID: " + group[1].Value);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("section: " + group[2].Value);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("roomID: " + group[3].Value);
```

Comment: Just to cover the bases, you do know the capture groups are in ``m.Groups``, yes?

Comment: I'm too new in regular expressions in C# and I don't have lots of experience to help you, but maybe you could use http://regexhero.net/tester/ and test your regular expression there, you make have in your mind that regular expressions may not be written the same way in different languages.

Comment: I got `[0-9]+[A-Z]+[0-9]+` maybe this helps :)

Comment: @user1705730 In RegExHero Tester, says your regular expression fits good for the string sample you give, can you give a sample that doesn't work for your regular expression? Thank you

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should make your regex a little more specific and limit how many numbers are allowed at the beginning/end.  How about:

`([1-9]{1,2})([A-Z])([1-9]{1,3})`

Next, the results of the captures (i.e. the 3 parts in parens) will be in the `Groups` property of your regex matcher object. I.e.

```
m.Groups[1] // First number
m.Groups[2] // Letter
m.Groups[3] // Second number
```

Comment: Thank you! (need more characters blabla)

Answer (score 0):

Regex.Matches(mdl.roomCode, "(\d+)([A-Z])(\d+)") returns an collection of matches. If there is no match, then it will return an empty MatchCollection.

Since the regular expression matches the string, it returns a colletion with one item, the input string.